# How do I change the background of my body when picking a color from my input with the type="color"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried adding a onclick event that when clicked changes the background to whatever is set in my input field but it did not work. I do not know if I am using a wrong event or if it is something else. Can someone please help me thank you.

```js
let color = document.getElementById("color-picker");

color.addEventListener("click", function() {colorPicker(color)});

    function colorPicker(chooseColor) {
        body.style.backgroundColor = chooseColor
    }
```

```html
<fieldset>
            <legend>Appearing here</legend>
            <div>
                <label for="color-picker">Colors</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="color" id="color-picker">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
```

Comment: document.body not just body.

Answer (score 2):

A few issues

1. the `change` event should be used instead of `click`
2. should be `document.body` instead of `body`
3. should use `chooseColor.value` to pick the value of the color picker

Answer (score 1):

1. *event "input"* would be much suitable for your intent.
2. *you passed the element* to the colorPicker function so *element's value has to be used*, not element itself.
3. *document.body* is correct, not just only body

```js
let color = document.getElementById("color-picker");

color.addEventListener("input", function() {colorPicker(color)});

function colorPicker(chooseColor) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = chooseColor.value;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Appearing here</legend>
    <div>
        <label for="color-picker">Colors</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="color" id="color-picker">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this by putting the `addEventListener` function all on one line (using an arrow `=>` function, and using an `onChange` event, not `onClick`. Then you want to return `color.value`, not the input element `color` itself. Finally, you want to use `document.body`, not `body`:

```js
let color = document.getElementById("color-picker")

color.addEventListener("change",() => document.body.style.backgroundColor = color.value)
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Appearing here</legend>
  <div>
    <label for="color-picker">Colors</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="color" id="color-picker">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```